# Why is posting on meta a disaster?

Tags: discussion

Look below is a screenshot of how I am losing points every day. All I can say is you may say posting here does not reduce the points.

But here is proof that you guys don't take kindly to suggestions/requests. It seems to be carried out with malice. On the one hand, you say don’t delete your profile. But on the other hand by your actions you seem to just want that.

Why must you every day target my previous questions and keep reducing points. Will you rest only when it’s zero? Is that what you want? How do I know I won’t be hounded again if I come back after 6 months? This seems unethical.

I have tried editing and improving some of the questions. No matter what I do, all I sense is continuous hostility.

Do you have any suggestions on how to stop this?

[image: Showing that its true am losing points ever since I posted on meta]

Comment: i guess best to close and leave

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already explained the Meta effect to you when you first posted here. By posting here about your questions, you are - for better or worse - drawing more attention to those questions than they would otherwise get.

Comment: As @F1Krazy commented the implicit expectation is that you *first* update your posts to be as good as possible and *then* shine meta light on them... Note that edits like https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76374684/revisions are unlikely make post better, but bring posts to attention of people who have "active" as home page even if they don't visit meta.

Comment: Note that signature lines most of the times are not the reason for downvotes. Most of the people who take an issue to it would simply edit it out. So the existing downvotes on your questions were probably due to other issues. Edits bump the post and bring attention to it, hence making minor edits like you've done would probably only bring more downvotes

Comment: Some of you guys have been nice in how you explain all this. Some have.  But my points are just sliding everyday. Somehow that just doesn't seem fair. Will give it one more try. Thank you.

Comment: I have done a cancel for my profile deletion now only because of some of the nicer people here.  I am rapidly losing my points every day since I posted on meta  . I do know about the meta effect. I do read whatever you say.  Not sure if you understand from my point of view. But  will give it a try. But it wont be practical to continue if the slide in points continues forever.

Comment: Writing questions is hard work and sometimes it doesn't feel all that rewarding because the optimal result is you never post the question.  A good question-asking process is also a good question-answering process. By the time you have fully examined the problem and investigated all of the options that you can think of, you've probably found the solution yourself. If you haven't, you either missed an option or what you want to do is impossible. Either way you're asking a question because there's no way for you to know which case you fell into.

Comment: @user4581301 interesting and  a bit philosophical is how I found your message. Certainly interesting. I did try formatting my last few questions and I believe I did get replies because they were good enough for the people who did answer. Previously I know at least one question was very tough and was dismissed as not code related or too unfocussed. A few months after my posting I found someone had created a whole project on that concept. Wanted to share but by then my question had been closed.

Comment: The meta effect is wild. Even when I don't ask about anything related to the main site, someone visits my stack overflow account and downvotes one of my posts

Comment: And that's not a nice or reasonable thing to do as its in no way helpful.

Comment: I suppose a lot of people mistakenly see SO primarily as a place to ask questions, rather than a place to find answers. Think of it as a textbook -- it's very hard to write a good one, but once it exists, it makes it easy for many people to learn from it. Finding novel and interesting questions is difficult after all the years this site existed, but I'd say that's a feature, not a bug. | As to the meta effect -- it's like advertising. You make yourself visible, you're bound to attract attention (and scrutiny). That's life.

Comment: Note: 1) [Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). 2) Like HTML, (single) newlines do ***not*** render here (unlike some other platforms). [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) (now with [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)).

Comment: "No matter what I do, all I sense is continuous hostility. Do you have any suggestions on how to stop this?" Did you try reading the advice you were given *in detail* and acting on it specifically, rather than treating any negative feedback as "hostile"?

Comment: @Dan Mašek - I totally agree on what you said. While my points continue to slide. I noticed one thing. On one of my questions there has been a turn around. The only change in that question from my point of view is I removed my signing Initial. Formatting wise it did not change that much. After I posted on meta that question developed negative points. But I suppose other than the dislikers the audience also had some people who read and understood what was the question. It now stands with a positive rating. Dont want to mention the question and again see it tank.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your posts on Meta don't (technically) have any bearing on your posts on main.  It could be the case that some people independently found your questions and didn't think they were that great, so they downvoted them.

Specifically [the question you're talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417362/using-cipherinputstream-instead-of-cipheroutputstream-when-encrypting), it's a bit tough to determine what your actual *question* is - you're saying that everything works but you're not sure if you're doing it right.  I don't think that's a *bad* question but I could see how it could trip someone up.

Something to emphasize - **no one is being hostile to *you***.  You're interpreting downvotes as hostility, and while I wish the system would say something about this, they're too busy trying to update the site with GenAI, so I'll say it instead.

**Don't take it personally.**

You should post a new Meta question here asking for feedback and what you could do to improve that post instead of just assuming we're out to get you.  Mostly because if you keep saying that we're out to get you, then we'll cease having a Q&A issue and start having a "you" issue, which isn't what any of us want to have.

Comment: but do see how it can become pointless if my points keep tanking everyday. All these dislikes have started like a flood since i asked just for a little help here. So I will wait and see. If it hits zero soon which is where it seems to be heading.

Comment: Lost 40 points by now and it might keep sliding till nothing is left

Comment: @Makato Will take on your suggestion and ask that question tomorrow. I am not sure if the dislikers even knew the subject topic as well as the person who answered - President James K. Polk-Strike. The dislikers seem to be out  to just dislike

Comment: I sort of disagree that you need another question that explains what your doing wrong when you have already asked that question and gotten fantastic feedback.

Comment: @Makato Security hound is actually right. Everything has been expalined. I have understood too. Within the limits of my time I have does some improvements also. Interestingly inspite of the flood of dislikes one question has shown a turnaround and the likes have overtaken the dislikes. I presume the technical readers who understood that question liked it and the flood of dislikers did dislike it initially but it did not get enough attention from them.

Comment: @RasterR downvotes, not dislikes. Using the wrong terminology is a hint you're winging it rather than hitting the books and figuring out how Stack Overflow works. This site will continue to appear quite nasty until you make the effort to understand it, because the site is pretty much 100% different from what you'll be used to. Any assumption you make is liable to be wrong.

Comment: @Gimby - that u are right. Will read it more thoroughly on weekend. Downvotes than dislikes. Each downvote is bringing down the reputation. Reached  almost 53 now from above 100. But point I am making is if this downvotes goes on I will soon be at 0 points. You can call it meta effect. But is that desirable?

Comment: To All. While its true that there was a huge downvotes to many past questions. I just wanted to say there have also been some positives. A few people spoke nicely. Some people have also requested approval for some edits. This not only helped me appreciate the editing but I think they were actually helping me get some points back. That would also be meta effect.

Comment: @RasterR - You can’t have 0 reputation.   If your contributions receive downvotes, improve them, to encourage upvotes.

Comment: @Raster you jumped in the biggest spotlight that Stack overflow has, where curators who want to improve the site roam. You then 'edited' all your questions by just removing your initial, which made them 'active' and visible again. But.... Without any significant improvement. It's not really surprising what's happening, even if it is unfortunate

Comment: @Patrice I would agree with you. Removing the initial is still an improvement from the rules deviation and it was pointed out.  I do think some people have been rather nice in how they advise. Some could be nicer.  And by the way points are now going down and up. I dont think they will hit zero.

Comment: @Raster yes it's an improvement. But editing your question brings attention to it. Removing a signature won't turn a bad question into a good one.... So editing to just remove a signature makes your questions visible, but not substantially better :/

Comment: @Patrice. That is true. You know other than the signature I thought I had improved quite a bit with my questions. Then I saw someone asked me to approve edits he did to one of my questions. The edits were so beautifully done. It was about grammar, using Caps for names. Like Poetry. Will try being like that when I get back my rights. A little tough. Anyways while I was consciously trying to improve for maybe a few weeks. Just around then like a needle on the haystack one of my questions was moved into another forum. That triggered my problem. :) Will hang in there. Will wait and see.